# Curl command works with Git CMD but not Git Bash on Windows

Tags: bash, curl, cmd

I have the curl command below:

```
curl -u <usr>:<pwd> ftp://taxsimftp.nber.org/tmp/[add randomly generated userid here].txm32 -o folder1/folder2/file.csv
```

which runs perfectly on my Mac with Git Bash and Git CMD on Windows, but produces the error:

> curl: (78) The file does not exist

when I run with Git Bash on Windows. What formatting differences may be necessary to allow the curl command to work in Windows with Git Bash as opposed to Git CMD?

To create the randomly generated userid I am using the code below in R:

```
library(stringr)

sample(letters, 10, replace = T) %>%
  str_c(collapse = "")
```

Comment: Please do not delete questions only to ask them again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71311827/curl-command-works-on-mac-but-not-windows - instead, edit the question so it's on topic

Comment: For example, tell us what errors are you getting?  are you able to run the command manually (w/o CURL)? what have you tried already?  all those details are helpful to answer the question

Comment: It's possible that the shell is expanding something in the username, the password, or the URL.  Surround all of them with quotes (e.g. `curl -u 'jane:football' 'ftp://...txm32' -o folder1/folder2/file.csv`).  Also, ensure that the output file is writable (`touch folder1/folder2/file.csv`).

Comment: "File does not exist": either curl is not accessible from Windows bash, or the csv file does not exist.  If it is curl, you need to adjust your PATH variable.  If it is the file, fix it with an existing file (and directories to get to it).

Comment: @pjh I tried using single and double quotes and that did not help. The file is writable since it works on my Mac with bash and cmd on my Windows

Comment: @blurfus thanks for your activity and concern on this post. Hiding the user and password is unnecessary as it is provided by National Bureau of Economic Research at https://users.nber.org/~taxsim/taxsim32/low-level-remote.html. I am not sure what you mean by running the command manually if you don't mind explaining. I am really interested in why bash on Windows wouldn't work with the same syntax that does work on my Mac with bash and cmd with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome the Git Bash difficulties on my Windows by using the code below in R. From there, one can write a csv with `readr`'s `write_csv` function.

```
library(RCurl)
library(magrittr)
library(readr)

url <- "ftp://taxsimftp.nber.org/tmp/[add randomly generated userid here].txm32"
data <- getURL(url, userpwd = "taxsim:02138") %>% 
  read_csv()
```